# How to set android as internet gateway for my home network

Tags: tethering, networking, gateway

Title should say all, but here's some network topology:

Laptop(s), desktop(s) **<-wlan/lan->** router **<-wifi->** android **<-internet->**

So I'd walk into the reach of my wifi and my android would connect to the wlan automatically and voila, internet for the rest of the network.

I think this is a good approach https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing and I'll probably figure the rest out myself before long, but if someone who knows what they are talking about could create a better guide or even an app for android for this, it would be much appreciated.

As for the use of this. e.g. range, network resilience (when used in mesh networking).

Thank you

Comment: This is probably rather a question concerning your router -- which should setup a default route to your Android device as soon as it's connected. In theory, this could work if the router always assigns the same IP to your Android device, and you configure this IP to be the default gateway all the time (so it would automagically work as soon as your Android device connects -- provided it connects while in Hotspot mode.

Comment: I've written a working answer for the same [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/246574). Hope it helps.